# Bytes object containing an arbitrary number of bits

Tags: python, cryptography, byte, bit, sha1

I'm currently implementing a platform to compare the execution time of different cryptographic algorithms in Python3.
One of the requirements of this platform is using the test vectors provided in the [NESSIE project](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/testvectors/hash/sha/Sha-1-160.test-vectors). While checking the test vectors I realized there are vectors such as

```
Set 2, vector#  3:
message=3 zero bits
hash=88BAD9D59A0A5195FAF7961BB6625486816C1430
```

This test vector requires an input of 3 zero-bits, that is '000' which arises a problem, the library I'm using [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) implements the SHA-1 function that only accepts as [input](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/cryptographic-hashes/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes.Hash.update) a **bytes** data type.

I've been reading the Python documentation and I wasn't able to find a way to generate a bytes object with only 3 bits, I'm only able to create them with 8,16,etc bits. I know this is the proper structure of a byte but, **is there a way to create or slice a byte object so it contains only 3 bits?**

If there's no way to do this, do you know about another cryptography library where these cases can be performed? (I'm not allowed to implement my own.)

Comment: The more important question is if you are planning to support such hashes with your platform. If you don't want to support SHA-1 generation of a 3 bits message I would simply ignore the test vector. Nearly every SHA-1 implementation I now only accepts bytes as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot slice a byte. A byte consists of 8 bits, presuming that a byte is an octet, as in all modern systems. Of course, there is a way to represent 3 bits, e.g. using a special data structure or by simply adding an integer that specifies how many bits are there to be used.

However, if you do not have a use case that requires a bit-oriented implementation then you can ignore the test vectors where the bits are not a full multiple of eight. Most libraries are byte-oriented, even if the algorithm is specified in bits. You *can* create a bit oriented from the spec, so the test vector needs to be there in case it is needed.

Unfortunately I have not found any statement from NIST to this affect, even if it is completely apparent from e.g. FIPS compliant libraries.